# How to delete Postgres files in Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I would like to delete my postgres volume and start over (learning the process). When I enter the postgres container using `docker exec -it [container_id] sh` I can see the postgres files like this: `ls var/lib/postgresql/data/`.

When I try to delete these files using `rm -r var/lib/postgresql/` I get:

> rm: can't remove 'var/lib/postgresql/data': Resource busy

If I stop this container, I will not be able to delete the volume. How can I delete it?

Fwiw my docker-compose looks as such:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Edit:

The docker-compose is pulled from my GitHub. I am not sure where any of the files are on the server. NVM, found them. Thanks.

Comment: You mounted the volume on your OS filesystem in `./postgres`. You can delete that folder. Or you can remove the volume with `docker volume rm volume_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mounted `./postgres` from your host system at ´/var/lib/postgresql/data` in your docker container:

```
volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

So just navigate to `./postgres` on your *host system* and delete the content.

You even can use Finder/Explorer to do this.
See also: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Answer (score 1):

The contents you can access from inside the container at /var/lib/postgresql/data, are the contents of the subdirectory postgres in the host machine, so you could add or remove files from the host machine

Comment: When I say subdirectory, I want to say "subdirectory of the directory where the docker-compose file is"